# passing value from ASP.NET to Java Scripts to HTML

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

I need value to be passing from ASP.NET page to JavaScript and then to HTML textfield.

My following code is able to read values from ASP.NET to JavaScript but unable to pass value form JavaScript to HTML TextField. Can anybody please correct my code.

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function can() {
            var myVariable = '<%=ServerSideVariable %>';
            document.write(myVariable);
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <input id="Text1" type="text" value='can()'/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string ServerSideVariable { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string pval = "Passed value;
        ServerSideVariable = pval;
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't pass the value like that from JavaScript to HTML.

Comment: Why? What's wrong? Is there any issues with this Daniel?

Comment: Because you aren't calling the function at all.

Comment: @Daniel - Is there any security issue while passing value in this manner?

Comment: @Daniel - But I found that the below code is working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said with javascript OR like this:

(since there is nothing in your example that requires javascript -- [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)-- don't use javascript if you don't have to do so.)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <input id="Text1" type="text" ><%=ServerSideVariable %></input>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can I write the same code using `myVariable` because while passing multiple values using this `ServerSideVariable` will not work.

Comment: @Kars - you should be able to "pass" multiple variable this way too.  What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: While passing multiple values individually how can I differentiate values using ` <%=ServerSideVariable %> ` So, is there any way to retrieve using `myVariable`

Comment: I still don't understand.  Just use a new escape for each place you want the value eg `var sam = <%=ServerSideVarSam%>; var smith = <%=ServerSideVarSmith%>`.  Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('Text1').value = myVariable;
```

But you need to move the assignment script block bellow the declaration of element Text1, or do it on document.ready

Anyway, you also need to error check.
It's best to use JQuery anyway, and get familiar with it.

Comment: Should I have to modify anything in `<input id="Text1" type="text" value='can()'/>`

Comment: @Kars - this probably did not work because you did not put it in before load.  If you move the javascript to a document ready or load event or the end of the file it should work just fine too.

Comment: @Hogan - Can you please post the syntax for me.

Comment: @quandary is correct with the syntax. (except `myVariable` can be replaced with `<%=ServerSideVariable %>`).  Just put the script tag between the `</form>` and `</body>` tags at the end of the document.

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead in a `document.load`.

```
document.getElementByID('Text1').value = myVariable;
```